# Active Admin not taking precompile assets on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

active admin not taking the precompile assets on production even it's present in public assets folder but it's taking different activeadmin.js and activeadmin.css file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In production usually public folder behave differently than development and staging. We got same issue our image was working fine on development but when we are doing it on production it was not working.

We moved it from public to assets and divided our scss/js with specific templates. As normally it adds everything in your assets/css file to one combined file.

So check during compile it take all assets files not public files. You can use public folder like normal link with image_Tag '/' So that mean for admin you have to create separate file manifest